# How To Import The MNIST Dataset From Local Directory Using PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am writing a code of a well-known problem `MNIST database of handwritten digits` in PyTorch. I downloaded the train and testing dataset (from the main website) including the labeled dataset. The dataset format is `t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz` and after extract `t10k-images-idx3-ubyte`. My dataset folder looks like

```
MINST
 Data
  train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
  train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
  t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
  t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
```

Now, I wrote a code to load data like bellow

```
def load_dataset():
    data_path = "/home/MNIST/Data/"
    xy_trainPT = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
        root=data_path, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
    )
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        xy_trainPT, batch_size=64, num_workers=0, shuffle=True
    )
    return train_loader
```

My code is showing `Supported extensions are: .jpg,.jpeg,.png,.ppm,.bmp,.pgm,.tif,.tiff,.webp`

How can I solve this problem and I also want to check that my images are loaded (just a figure contains the first 5 images) from the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this [Extract images from .idx3-ubyte file or GZIP via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427435/extract-images-from-idx3-ubyte-file-or-gzip-via-python)

**Update**

You can import data using this format

```
xy_trainPT = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    root="~/Handwritten_Deep_L/",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()]),
)
```

Now, what is happening at `download=True` first your code will check at the root directory (your given path) contains any datasets or not.

If `no` then datasets will be downloaded from the web.

If `yes` this path already contains a dataset then your code will work using the existing dataset and will not download from the internet.

You can check, first give a path `without any dataset` (data will be downloaded from the internet), and then give another path `which already contains dataset` data will not be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow !

The MNIST dataset is not stored as images, but in a binary format (as indicated by the ubyte extension). Therefore, `ImageFolder`is not the type dataset you want. Instead, you will need to use the [MNIST dataset class](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classtorch_1_1data_1_1datasets_1_1_m_n_i_s_t.html). It could even download the data if you had not done it already :)

This is a dataset class, so just instantiate with the proper `root` path, then put it as the parameter of your dataloader and everything should work just fine.

If you want to check the images, just use the `get`method of the dataloader, and save the result as a [png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image) file (you may need to convert the tensor to a numpy array first).

Comment: thank you. Do you mean like this?

    `data_path = "/data/MNIST/raw"`
    

     `xy_trainPT = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
        root=data_path, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()`

Comment: yeah there may be a transform required, you can take inspiration from https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py

Comment: But this is not working 
Showing `Dataset not found. You can use download=True to download it` but the path is right

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I came across this post because I was facing a similar issue. I already had the MNIST folder downloaded (via pytorch dataset) somewhere else in my repository and I didn't want to redownload it again when I needed in a different source file.

My problem was that when passing the `root` argument, I was referencing the `MNIST/` folder but you should actually be referencing the **parent folder that contains the MNIST/ directory**.  In fact the [docs](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.MNIST.html) mention:

> root (string) – Root directory of dataset where MNIST/raw/train-images-idx3-ubyte and MNIST/raw/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte exist.

So I figured the `MNIST/` part of the path should be omitted.

So in my case I had:
`mnist_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='../MNIST/', train=True, download=False)`

Hope this helps

which should be changed to:
`mnist_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='../', train=True, download=False)`