# Importing MNIST dataset from local directory in a closed system

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, mnist

I am trying to run a tutorial based on MNIST data in a cluster and the node where training script runs don't have internet access so I am manually placing the MNIST dataset in the desired directory but I am getting `Dataset not found error.`
I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/examples/pytorch/pytorch_mnist.py) tutorial on the cluster.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080130/how-to-import-the-mnist-dataset-from-local-directory-using-pytorch) answer but the answer doesn't resolve my problem.
Below is my code modifications -

```
import horovod.torch as hvd
train_dataset = \
datasets.MNIST('/scratch/netra/MNIST/processed/training.pt-%d' % hvd.rank(), train=True, download=True,
               transform=transforms.Compose([
                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
               ]))
test_dataset = \
datasets.MNIST('/scratch/netra/MNIST/processed/test.pt-%d' % hvd.rank(), train=False, 
               transform=transforms.Compose([
                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
               ]))
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a root folder, not a full path to the processed file:

> `root (string)`: Root directory of dataset where `MNIST/processed/training.pt`
> and  `MNIST/processed/test.pt` exist.

In your case:

`root is /scratch/netra`

Thus,

```py
train_dataset = \
datasets.MNIST('/scratch/netra-%d' % hvd.rank(), train=True, download=True,
               transform=transforms.Compose([
                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
               ]))
test_dataset = \
datasets.MNIST('/scratch/netra-%d' % hvd.rank(), train=False, 
               transform=transforms.Compose([
                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
               ]))
```

Comment: I think the problem is horovod extension because it is still giving the same error but if I am using it without horovod then it works fine.

Comment: Try to debug `hvd.rank()` or try f-strings: `f"/scratch/netra-{hvd.rank()}"`

Answer (score 1):

If the above does not work, try putting those .pt files in a folder called `.data` in your current working directory:

```
import os
CURR_DIR = os.getcwd()
print(CURR_DIR)

train = datasets.MNIST(root='./data',download=False, train=True,
               transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                             transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))]))
# works

train = datasets.MNIST(root=CURR_DIR + '\\data',
                       download=False, train=True,
               transform=transforms.Compose([
                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))]))
# works

# same files also in this folder
train = datasets.MNIST(root=CURR_DIR + '\\processed',download=False, train=True,
               transform=transforms.Compose([
                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                   transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
               ]))
# Dataset not found
```

Interestingly, in the last example, this is precisely the location that the torch MNIST data set class that generates the data places the .pt files.

Comment: I think the problem is horovod extension because it is still giving the same error but if I am using it without horovod then it works fine.